# Use sAMAcountName from ldap as username

Tags: ldap, keycloak

I connected our active directory to keycloak (4.0.0.Beta1) and imported the users - this works fine.

But the username should be filled from `sAMAccountName`. So i changed the `Username LDAP attribute` to that.

But after clicking `Synchronize all users` i am getting this error in the console window:

```
8:20:13,372 ERROR [org.keycloak.storage.ldap.LDAPStorageProviderFactory] (default task-119) Failed during import user from LDAP: org.keycloak.models.ModelException: User returned from LDAP has null username! Check configuration of your LDA
 mappings. Mapped username LDAP attribute: cn, user DN: CN=Mustermann Max,OU=Normung,OU=Mech,OU=Konstruktion,OU=Abteilungen,DC=company,DC=org, attributes from LDAP: {whenChanged=[2017037125253.0Z], whenCreated=[20140520092805.0
], mail=[Max.Mustermann@company.org], givenName=[Max], sn=[Mustermann], userAccountControl=[66048], pwdLastSet=[130750516258418527]}
       at org.keycloak.storage.ldap.LDAPUtils.getUsername(LDAPUtils.java:113)
       at org.keycloak.storage.ldap.LDAPStorageProviderFactory$3.run(LDAPStorageProviderFactory.java:521)
       at org.keycloak.models.utils.KeycloakModelUtils.runJobInTransaction(KeycloakModelUtils.java:227)
       at org.keycloak.storage.ldap.LDAPStorageProviderFactory.importLdapUsers(LDAPStorageProviderFactory.java:514)
       at org.keycloak.storage.ldap.LDAPStorageProviderFactory.syncImpl(LDAPStorageProviderFactory.java:469)
       at org.keycloak.storage.ldap.LDAPStorageProviderFactory.sync(LDAPStorageProviderFactory.java:407)
...
```

I tried some mappers (especially `username`) but with no luck. It seems that there are only a few attributes read from the ldap server (see `attributes from LDAP:...` in the output).

Namely: whenChanged, whenCreated, mail, givenName, sn, userAccountControl, pwdLastSet.

How can i get the sAMAcountName attribute as username?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I have just tested it in 4.1.0.Final and there it works when you change the *Username LDAP attribute* to *sAMAccountName* **and additionally** the 
*LDAP Attribute* in the *username* mapper also to *sAMAccountName*.

> I tried some mappers (especially username) but with no luck.

Your question suggest, that you already tried doing something in the username mappers. So you were definetly on the right track. Either there was a bug in your version, or the two fields didn't match correctly.

Comment: Works, thanx. Do you know what to do to fill the 'First Name' column in the users table? I did some mapping but again with no luck.

Comment: I ran into same issue migrating from a working 3.x ok Keycloak to 4.x. Changing mapping as mentioned it works again. Tks

Answer (score 17):

For me, it worked. Please find the below process:

1) In User Federation -> LDAP Provider -> There is a setting called "UserName LDAP Attribute". (as shown here [ldap provider settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vJh5G.png))

2) Select Mappers tab and edit "username" mapper and change to following settings: [username mapper settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VJIhg.png)